# wpf datagridcheckboxcolumn: how to enable/disable checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. The grid has a binding with a list of objects. I want that, if there are N checkboxes checked, the unchecked become disabled, but I don't know how to perform the disable.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn
    x:Name="IsFixedByBracketColumn"
    Header="Fissato con staffa"
    Binding="{Binding isFixedByBracket, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            Binding="{Binding
                                HasMaxNumberReached,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            Value="true"/>
                        <Condition
                            Binding="{Binding
                                IsChecked,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                            Value="false"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <EventSetter
                Event="CheckBox.Checked"
                Handler="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>                                        
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Code for the event:

```
private void DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (cb.IsChecked == true)
    {
        this.numberOfCheckboxesChecked++;
    }
    else
    {
        this.numberOfCheckboxesChecked--;
    }

    if (this.numberOfCheckboxesChecked >= maxNumOfPointsPerSide)
    {               
        this.HasMaxNumberReached = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.HasMaxNumberReached = false; 
    }              
}

public bool HasMaxNumberReached
{
    get {
        return hasMaxNumberReached;
    }
    set { 
        hasMaxNumberReached = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("HasMaxNumberReached");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Magnus in MSDN Forum, here is the correct answer of the problem:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="style">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding HasMaxNumberReached, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" />
                <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="IsFixedByBracketColumn"  Header="Fissato con staffa" 
                                Binding="{Binding isFixedByBracket, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource style}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource style}">

        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2257ead7-da3f-4f23-997a-afc35837b3e4/wpf-datagridcheckboxcolumn-how-to-enabledisable-checkboxes?forum=wpf#2257ead7-da3f-4f23-997a-afc35837b3e4) the complete topic

Comment: Two years later I want to say thank you because this solved a different issue I was having. DataGrid.Columns is not part of the design tree in WPF so when you have bindings, like on the checkboxcolumn, you can't do a RelativeSource AncestorType search on say... the main window. So you can't bind to the window's datacontext, you have to bind to the datagrid's datacontext which can be different in certain situations. HOWEVER your solution of putting the style in the datagrid resources allow for the relative source to be bound to the window, thus the checkbox column can now bind to it via proxy!

Answer (score 0):

you can set `DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle` to enable/disable cell as explained below. Here assuming `HasMaxNumberReached` is a property on your ViewModel which tell that the count of max checkbox checked has reached.

```
  <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Checkbox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding HasMaxNumberReached, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>                               
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <EventSetter
                              Event="CheckBox.Checked"
                               Handler="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>



 private bool hasMaxNumberReached;
 public bool HasMaxNumberReached
 {
  get 
     {return hasMaxNumberReached;}
  set 
     {
      hasMaxNumberReached =value; 
       RaisePropertyChanged("HasMaxNumberReached");
       }
  }
```

Comment: so it is not needed to do anything via code (excluding HAsMaxNumberReached management)?

Comment: but in this way do I disable only the unchecked one?

Comment: I've tried the code. TargetType="DataGridCell" does not work, raises an exception. If I change it to CheckBox, the event CellEditEnding is not fired...

Comment: @Farzi it works, but the event CellEditEnding in which I change the value of HasMaxNumberReached is never fired...plus the checkbox is checked/unchecked only clicking in the cell that contains the checkbox, differing from previous behaviour in which the checkbox is checked/unchecked clicking only on checkbox...

Comment: @nit you need to suggest me where must I update the value of HasMaxNumberReached , because before I've used the event CellEditEnding , and now this event is never fired

Comment: event not getting fired? hasMaxNumberReached is property rt not variable? and it has PropertyChanged fired from the setter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38605/discussion-between-francescods-and-nit)

Comment: If you are talking about the event that I described above, yes it is always fired

Comment: then you have to implement the property like i did in the updated answer..and make sure to raise PropertyChanged for it.. i hope you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented

Comment: thats what you need to do... and it will work.. currently your property change is not notified to the UI

Comment: @nit where can I find some tutorial about it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: @nit the tutorial is for windows Forms...are there differences between Forms and WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with the help of [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx), like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">  
 <Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
 </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

and you can apply this style to your checkbox

Comment: adding styles changes the behaviour of checkboxes in my datagridcheckboxcolumn...all checkboxes are not centered but, after double click on cell container, they returns magically on center of the cell...as long as I select another cell